# Add only unique pairs from a list

Tags: c++, algorithm

say I have:

listA.

I think have a function:

bool isValidPair(a,b);

If that function returns true for a b, it will be true for b a too.

In the naive case I would have this:

```
for each a in listA
for each b in listA
{
   if(a != b && isValidPair(a,b) && 1istC.contains(a,b))
     {
        listC.add(a,b);
     }
}
```

However this involves the contains function but I'm wondering if there is a clever way I could do this in an efficient way.

I'm actually looking for pairs of colliding axis aligned Bounding Boxes. I will then use impulse resolution on these pairs.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't this be `!1istC.contains(a,b)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use an existing algorithm. If I have understood your question correctly, [`std::set_intersection()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) does the work:

```
int main()
{
    //For example: Lists of ints;

    std::vector<int> a = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 11 , 13 };
    std::vector<int> b = { 1 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 9 , 11 , 13 };
    std::vector<int> result;

    std::set_intersection( std::begin( a ) , std::end( a ) ,
                           std::begin( b ) , std::end( b ) ,
                           std::back_inserter( result )
                         );
}
```

The content of `result` after the execution is:

> 1 3 5 7 11 13

Comment: But ... there's only 2 lists (1 input, 1 output). +4? 5 people didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` is a container that without duplicate.

`std::set` need `operator <` defined (or custom equivalent functor)
As you want to treat `{a, b}` as `{b, a}`
I used a special comparator which treat {a, b} as `{min(a, b), max(a, b)}`
and let the provided comparator of pair do the job.

Following may help:

```
template <typename T>
struct unorderLess
{
    bool operator () (const std::pair<T, T>& lhs, const std::pair<T, T>& rhs) const
    {
        const auto lhs_order = lhs.first < lhs.second ? lhs : std::tie(lhs.second, lhs.first);
        const auto rhs_order = rhs.first < rhs.second ? rhs : std::tie(rhs.second, rhs.first);

        return lhs_order < rhs_order;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::set<std::pair<int, int>, unorderLess<int>> s;

    s.insert({50, 42});
    s.insert({42, 50});
    s.insert({50, 42});
    s.insert({42, 42});

    assert(s.size() == 2); // {42, 42}, {50, 42}

    return 0;
}
```